# Very slow running queries across local network in c# apps

Tags: c#, database

I've been developing some small database applications in Visual Studio C# for a while now. I am currently using VS 2010. Up until recently all the apps were ran on the same computer that the database was stored on and everything ran great.  Recently I had to start to developing some apps that will run on a separate computer that is on the same local network.

Easy enough, but I run into a problem when running queries to fill controls, such as a grid or even combo box.  The problem is that it can take 15-30 seconds per control if my query is pulling a large amount of data.  I know this is because the app is sending out my select query, waiting for all of the results to come across the network and then displaying the information.  The problem is I don't know what to do about it.

Below I have a code snippet(slightly modified to make more sense).  It is using a Firebird database, though I use MSSQL and Sybase Advantage as well with the same results.

```
            FbConnection fdbConnect = new FbConnection();
            fdbConnect.ConnectionString = Program.ConnectionString;
            fdbConnect.Open();
            FbCommand fcmdQuery = new FbCommand();
            fcmdQuery.Connection = fdbConnect;
            fcmdQuery.CommandText = "select dadda.name, yadda.address, yadda.phone1 from SOMETABLE left join yadda on dadda               where yadda.pk = dadda.yaddapk";
            FbDataAdapter fdaDataSet = new FbDataAdapter(fcmdQuery);
            DataSet dsReturn = new DataSet();
            fdaDataSet.Fill(dsReturn);
            fdbConnect.Close();
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dsReturn.Tables[0];
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can speed this up?

Comment: How much is "large amount of data"? Have you identified the bottleneck (network, DB, something else)?

Comment: Also, what's the databases?  Things like Access (.MDB) backends are notoriously slow when accessed across a network.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Firebird...SO mentioned that.

Comment: @Reniuz Ahh, sorry, missed that.

Comment: when you executing query in that pc where database is, getting results fast?

Comment: @Reniuz, yes.  For all practical purposes instant.

Comment: @Oded Can be between 100-500k records and between 3-10 columns.

Comment: have you tried commenting out the .DataSource line to see if your bottleneck is the retrieval of data or the population of the DGV?

Comment: @0A0D I've troubleshot it done to this line "fdaDataSet.Fill(dsReturn);".  Everything before that is near instant, setting the datasource after the dataset has been created is about a .3-.5 second gap, so that isn't really a bottle neck.

Answer (score 1):

You may returning unnecessary data in that SELECT * statement. It can be wasteful in network traffic and drive down the performance of your application. There are many articles about this and how you should specify your columns explicitly. Here is [one in particular](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list).

Comment: Good information, but i actually explicitly target specific columns in my real code, I just wrote a quick fake SQL and didn't think about the select * confusing people.   Thanks!

Comment: @thebuder: Remember to give us accurate information when asking your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the volume of the response by restricting your columns:

Instead of

```
select * from SOMETABLE
```

Try

```
 select a,b,c from SOMETABLE
```

to retrieve only the data you need.

Your mileage vary depending on what the table contains. If there are unused blob columns for instance, you are adding a considerable overhead to your response.

Comment: I edited my post. I actually do retrieve only the columns and data that I need.

Comment: In that case, as others have suggested,server side paging to limit the size of your dataset is probably the low hanging fruit

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the data in `gridview`, and if data is **huge**, its better to do server side paging so that a specific number of rows is returned at a time.

Comment: I am going to check into this and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I just got back to work on this.  I have been looking into server side paging and am having some problem with my research.  First problem is I am using WinForms, and it seems all search results yield ASP results which don't seem to carry over well.  The second problem is that the bottle neck is actually filling the SQL statement, so anything that I do with the gridview I don't see as helping.

Any suggestion on where to look for more information on server side paging with winforms? I freely admit I don't even know where to enable server side paging, on datasource or something on the database.